# DataGridViewRow no aparece

Tags: c#

Necesito usar: DataGridViewRow pero no aparece[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: adiciona el using: System.Windows.Forms, si no te aparece agregalo a tu proyecto el ensamblado System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya quedo.